# How to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2k}{k} (sp)^kq^{k}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2k}{k} (sp)^kq^{k}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2k}{k} (sp)^kq^{2k - k}$

I know that if I had a truncation, ie, $\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{2k}{k} (sp)^kq^{k}$, I would have $\sum_{k = 0}^{N} \binom{2k}{k} (sp)^kq^{k} = (sp + q)^N$.

But I do not know to where this sum converges...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function of the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{2k}k$ is

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}kx^k\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}k(sp)^kq^k=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}k(spq)^k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4spq}}$$

within the radius of convergence.

Your expression for the finite sum cannot be correct: for $N=1$ it says that $1+2spq=sp+q$.

Perhaps you’re thinking of the binomial theorem, which says that

$$(sp+q)^N=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}k(sp)^kq^{N-k}\;.$$

Comment: I'm sorry... I edited my post! I guess it is correct now! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Luísa: The finite sum still can’t be right; I suspect that you’re thinking of the binomial theorem but getting the details wrong.

Comment: Yeah.. I was thinking of the binomial! I'm sorry

Comment: @Luísa: No need to apologize: we all have the occasional mental hiccup.